# Which one is better, including all JS files in head or at the end of body?

Tags: performance

I am totally confused about the loading speed and accessability of my js files. When I try to include a piece of jQuery before the `<head>` section i recieve errors. But including JS's at the end causes many efford because I am not able to use footer.

Do you have any suggestions, why?

Comment: What about placing it *in* the `head` section?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is sime always add js files nearer to the  close tag. Why because js file loading will blocks all other elements loading till js file is loaded completely.

So add all the JS before the body close tag.